# index contains duplicate entries cannot reshape

Tags: pandas, pivot

I have following data,

| Unnamed: 5 | Week | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Quartiles | Week5 | 3 |
| CR | Week4 | 2 |
| KPI | Week3 | 1 |
| Quartiles | Week5 | 2 |
| CR | Week4 | 5 |
| KPI | Week3 | 1 |

I am trying to convert like this

| Week | Quartiles | CR | KPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week5 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| Week4 | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| Week3 | 1 | 1 | 4 |

While running the following code:

```
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df2,values='value',index='variable',columns='Unnamed: 5',aggfunc='first')
```

I got following error,

```
"Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"
```

I tried different agg function nothing works..

I dont need agg function, I just need to update values as it is...

Comment: Are you sure used `pivot_table` ? Because error `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` is if use `pivot`

Comment: Are data correct for `Week` column in input? From ouput is should be 3 times `Week5` and then 3 times `Week4`

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(df,values='Value',index='Week',columns='Unnamed: 5',aggfunc='first')` Works just fine... what is it you're actually doing?

Comment: @BeRT2me, index='week' contains multiple duplicate rows, thats why it is throwing error, if I use aggregation function it is shrinking to only 5 rows, but I dont want that. how to skip aggregation and pivot the table as it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)